# Using xslt with <amp-img>

Tags: xslt, amp-html

My website has the content in an xml file, and displays it using an xsl stylesheet, so the customer can easily edit the content, but if I use `amp-img` tags, the xsl transformation self-closes the tags even though I used a closing tag in the stylesheet. Then, when I use the w3c html validator to test the page it gives errors saying that the following tag was not closed. Here is an example of the errors:

Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

Error: End tag div seen, but there were open elements.

```
<amp-img width="30" height="30" src="/images/camera.svg" />
```

Could anyone advise how I can deal with this?

Here is part of the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//localItem" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="localItem">
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
<div class="breadCrumb" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
   <a itemprop="item" href="localSights.aspx">
     <h2 class="traffic" itemprop="name">
       <xsl:value-of select="heading" />
     </h2>
     <meta itemprop="position">
       <xsl:attribute name="content">
         <xsl:value-of select="@position"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
     </meta>
     <div class="breadCrumbIcon">
       <amp-img>
     <xsl:attribute name="width">
       <xsl:value-of select="image/@width"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="height">
       <xsl:value-of select="image/@height"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
       <xsl:value-of select="image"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     </amp-img>
     </div>
     <div class="description">
           <xsl:value-of select="paragraph"/>
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
 </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is an element from the xml file:

```
  <page name="nearby">
    <localItem position="1">
      <heading>Local Sights</heading>
      <paragraph>
        Lincoln is a historic city...Click here to see some of the many sights
      </paragraph>
      <image alt="drawing of camera" width="30" height="30">/images/camera.svg</image>
    </localItem>
</page>
```

Here is the vb.net code in the amp page:

```
        <%
        Dim root As XmlElement
        root = Cache("content").documentElement
        Dim styleFile As String = (EdenHouseContent.webRoot & "\nearby\default.xslt")
        Response.Write(httpFunctions.transformXML(root.OuterXml, styleFile))
    %>
```

And here is the used-defined function called above:

```
    Public Shared Function transformXML(xmlNode As Object, styleSheet As Object) As String
    Dim reader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(New IO.StringReader(xmlNode.ToString()))
    reader.MoveToContent()

    'Load the style sheet. 
    Dim xslt As System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform = New System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform()
    'xslt.OutputSettings.ConformanceLevel = System.Xml.ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    xslt.Load(styleSheet)

    ' Transform the node fragment
    Dim settings As System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings = New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True
    settings.Indent = True
    settings.ConformanceLevel = System.Xml.ConformanceLevel.Auto
    settings.CloseOutput = False

    Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim writer As Object = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings)
    xslt.Transform(reader, writer)
    Return (sw.ToString())

End Function
```

Here is the top of the  stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  I hope this is what you meant.  This is the first time I have posted a question.  I'm not sure if you would like the url of the page.

Comment: I can't even tell what your stylesheet's output method is, let alone try and run the actual transformation myself.

Comment: I have added the first lines from the stylesheet.  The output method is not explicitly declared.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<xsl:output method="html"/>` if you want to produce output that an HTML parser will accept.